# Compare coefficients from different regression equations in R

Tags: r, regression, hypothesis-testing

I am trying to compare differences between coefficients in different regression equations. Specifically, I have 2 regressions looking at the effect of Importance to Donate on Guilt, Feeling, and Responsibility.

```
aov_I <- aov(AV_importance_to_donate~AV_guilty+AV_percieved_resp+feeling_I, newdata_I)
summary(aov_I)

aov_S <- aov(AV_importance_to_donate~AV_guilty+AV_percieved_resp+feeling_S, newdata_S)
summary(aov_S)
```

I would like to compare the differences between the coefficients in these two different regression equations. E.g., is one significantly higher than the other?

How can I do this?

Comment: Try to combine two models into one by creating dummy variables, then you can construct the test.

Comment: Questions solely about how software works are
[off-topic](https://stats.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) here, but
you may have a real statistical question buried here. 
You may want to edit your question to clarify the underlying 
statistical issue. You may find that when you understand 
the statistical concepts involved, the software-specific elements are 
self-evident or at least easy to get from the documentation.

Comment: What is the difference between `newdata_I` & `newdata_S`? Why are they used in two separate models? Do you have access to the raw data from each?

Comment: Note that in R, you can set the second argument to `aov()` (ie, the `data` argument) so that you don't need to include the dataset for each variable. This will make for shorter & more comprehensible code.

Comment: Hi @gung thanks for your comments. This was a psychology study in which participants viewed a photo of either a statistical victim or an individual victim. newdata_I represents the data of those who viewed the individual victim, whilst newdata_S represents those who viewed the statistical victims.

Comment: Out of curiosity, what is a "statistical victim"? Is this a poor undergraduate student, forced to take statistics as part of their degree program, who got a mean statistics teacher?

Comment: @gung hahah! its a study on the identifiable victim effect, so comparing showing an individual, identified victim (with a picture, name, age, etc) to a statistical appeal (only giving numbers and statistics)

Comment: @user158565 is on the right track, I think.  Otherwise my answer at https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/76475/principal-component-analysis-whether-a-variable-is-significantly-loaded-on-a-pr may be helpful.